# Can't use @model with @inherit in Umbraco 7

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, content-management-system, umbraco

I've implemented Entity Framework into my project, since I need to insert some data via a form to a custom table in my SQL database.

I've scaffolded all the CRUD views and have a button that links to the create view. This all works well and fine, but I need the create view to use the Master template that contains my header, navigation and footer.

In my create view I need to import my model, but I am unable to both use the @model and the @inherit keywords in the same file, so I am unable to inherit the master template.

Is it not possible to use Entity Framework with Umbraco? Do I need to create a partial view or Macro?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a master page you have to set it at the header of the page like this: 
If the name of the master page is Master here is the code.

```
@{
    Layout = "Master.cshtml";
 }
```

If you are using a umbraco page and you want to pass some custom objects from your controller here is the code for that:

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoViewPage<List<ViewModel>>
```

If you are using only custom logic from backend which is not related to umbraco dashboard itself you dont need a macro!

Remember to inherit from `SurfaceController`.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34296463/passing-a-custom-model-into-a-umbraco-partial-view-and-getting-object-casting-er) is another question which may tell you more in details how to create your model and pass it to the view.

Remember your model should iherit from 'RenderModel' and you have to use umbraco form to post data back to the server as well.

If you have anything else unclear just let me know!

Answer (score 0):

You also may wish to consider the concept of a headless CMS. That way, your views, models or anything in your app won't be necessarily dependent on the classes of your CMS. There are numerous headless CMSes in the market. Although I work with one of the vendors, I really want you to choose to your own preferences.